# UITableView border with rounded corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to show the border (Width: 5, Color: Any) with rounded corner radius (Eg: 5) on UITableView?

Comment: you did something than post here ...

Comment: self.tableview.layer's corner radius

Comment: @Bhavin: Actually, I don't have the screenshot or code right now. But I'll do it.

Comment: @PKT; Actually problem is, suppose you have border color is Blue and corner radius is 5. Then on all four corners, the top most and bottom cell's color (Say White)....seems white as a little bit.

Comment: are you tried the tableview or table contentVIew

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: tableView.layer   @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @iDev750 - can you show your code is easy to solve bro

Comment: given answer for your question.....if u like, accept the answer by clicking checkmark beside answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import the `QuartzCore` framework, (ex: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`) then use this code,

```
TableViewName.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

TableViewName.layer.borderWidth = 5;

TableViewName.layer.cornerRadius=5;
```

Its will give you rounded corners without having to add your tableview to a superView or clipping it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and add this in **viewDidLoad**

```
tableView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
tableView.layer.cornerRadius= 5.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add QuartzCore Framework in the project
Then import the framework in the class as below

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then in ViewdidLoad do

```
yourTableViewName.layer.borderColor = [UIColor gray].CGColor;
yourTableViewName.layer.borderWidth =  3.0;
yourTableViewName.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
```

Hope this Helps!